# Interchanging videos on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, video, html5-video

I'm trying to have a video play over another video and then disappear again.

I have a background video (http://stefanerickson.github.io/covervid/) that i've set to auto play.

```html
<section class="masthead">
        <video class="masthead-video" autoplay loop muted poster="assets/images/poster.jpg">
            <source src="img/video/box_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="img/video/box_1.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
</section>
```

The idea is that on click another video will play over it and then disappear.

Any pointers and advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are both videos playing at the same time? Or will the video behind the other one be paused?

Comment: If you want the second video to play while 1st is playing, you could use a modal.

Comment: It can be paused. Eatherway would work.